# Remove "dots" noise (like from dot-matrix printer)

Tags: textures, opengl-es, procedural-generation

I have 2D array of floats. Using the floats, I generate image by doing proportional selection of color from between COLOR_MIN, COLOR_MAX – for maximal float value at given (x,y), I choose COLOR_MAX and put pixel at (x,y), for minimum float value – I choose COLOR_MIN.

Resulting 128x128 image (created from 128x128 float array) is then used as texture, which is then scaled to about 500x500 size. Image displayed this way has "dot-noise", like if the image would be printed from needle printer (example image/screenshot attached below).

**How to avoid the noise**? I could scale the image myself to 512x512, but I probably need some filtering? Or will be setting some OpenGL (ES) options for the texture sufficient?

[image: Distorted image]

**PS.:** The image is result of GL_LINEAR magnifying filter. Using GL_NEAREST results in large pixels being clearly visible (green below). So apparently, I need programmatic filter to run on CPU.

[image]

Comment: Well it appears the colors values themselves are wobbling, or oscillating. If that's the case then this is the expected result. Can you post the `GL_NEAREST` results so we can look at it?

Comment: @bobobobo: I have added the GL_NEAREST image.

Comment: How come your uploaded images are neither 128x128 nor 512x512? You should post the original sized images, otherwise it's really hard to judge.

Comment: So yeah.  The issue is the underlying data is bumpy.  You need to first smooth the _data_ before generating the texture, just by averaging or low pass filtering.

Comment: @bo Should be an answer.